# Visual Studio Invalid Bootstrapper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, bootstrapper, prerequisites

I have a bunch of programs set up as prerequisites in the VS bootstrapper.  Recently, everytime I build on my machine and try to run setup.exe, I get an error ".....msi has either changed or been corrupted since the package was originally published".  I know this isn't a problem with the setup or the msi files because I done the exact same thing on another development machine and copied the output to my  machine and it's worked.  I figure it must be something within the visual studio - bootstrapper connection.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the log file ActivityLog.xml. It's under AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

You need to run Visual Studio this way "Devenv /log"

Comment: I don't see any ActivityLog in that folder.  Is there anywhere else it could be?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say you have to pass "/log" parameter to devenv.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

Comment: I did that, still can't seem to find the file.  This could be because it's not actually throwing an error during the build.  It just gives me an error when I run setup.exe.